# how to create a generic singleton class in java?

Tags: java, generics

i want to create a generic singleton class in java witch gives singleton object of class which i pass in method parameter. some thing like below code : please help

```
public final class Listener<T extends Object>  {
    private Listener() {
    }

    public static <T> Listener<?> getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        public static final Listener INSTANCE = new Listener();
        // private static final Map<Class<? extends Runnable>,Listener<? extends
        // Runnable> INSTANCE = new ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be generic? In your example you are not using T in any way.

Comment: it could be usefull. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286762/how-parametrize-generic-singleton-in-java

Comment: Won't this result nbe a breach of the whole idea the singleton is based on (only have one instance of that class)?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If it is a real singleton, it cannot be really generic, because you have to chose the type parameter on creation. Or do you want one instance per T type?

Comment: Btw, a generified singleton definitely can make sense -- as long as it doesn't ever take or give out instances of its generic parameter. `Collections.empty[List|Map|Set]()` return singleton instances which fail if you try to add or get any elements. The `emptyList` (etc) methods have an unchecked cast to turn the singleton into a `List<T>` (same for the other collection interfaces).

Comment: To be more specific: it can accept `T`s as long as it only assumes they're objects; and it gen return `T`s as long as they're always null.

Answer (score 7):

Make an `enum` with just one value, `INSTANCE` or such. Instant singleton.

If I understand you correctly, I think you want your singleton to implement some generic interface? Something like:

```
interface ListenerInterface<T> {
    void handleEvent(T event);
}
```

In that case, you can use an unchecked cast to return your enum-as-singleton in a generified way. This is safe as long as your singleton doesn't actually use the instance (or else, only assume it's an Object).

```
public enum MySingleton implements ListenerInterface<Object> {
    INSTANCE;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> ListenerInterface<T> getListener() {
        return (ListenerInterface<T>) INSTANCE;
    }

    public void handleEvent(Object event) {
        System.out.println("I am a singleton. An event happened: " + event);
    }

}
```

If the interface is a producer instead of consumer -- that is, it returns a `T` -- then you can only return `null` safely. Otherwise, someone else will get a ClassCastException when they try to use their `T`, which they think is a Foo but is actually just an Object.

Comment: +1 , i also don't get why the downvote , it is trivial and simple, good solution, here is also a good link for a discussion about an Enum being a singleton implementation http://closingbraces.net/2011/07/04/enum-as-singleton/

Answer (score 3):

This was going to be comment but I think it better be an answer due to character limit,

Thinking little bit deeper will it be really possible to create a generic singleton class?

> A singleton class can not be instantiated neither should it be cloned.

To give any class this behavior you will have to  make `all the constructors private and clone method will have to be overridden to throw an exception`. Now if you are going to change all your classes to implement this behavior is your way of creating singleton really generic?

Please excuse me if I interpreted the question wrongly

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, but is unreliable IMHO:

```
public class SimpleSingleton {
private Map<String, Object> counter = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public <T> T getInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    T singleton = (T) counter.get(clazz.getName());
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = clazz.newInstance();
        counter.put(clazz.getName(), singleton);
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me to this problem was designing it like this:

```
public interface IListener<T extends Object>  {
    void handle(T event);
}

public final class Listener implements IListener<Object> {
    private static Listener instance = new Listener();

    private Listener() {
    }

    public static Listener getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Object event) {
        //TODO Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question fully, but if you want to integrate a singleton into a generic hierarchy, you have to cheat a bit (like we did in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4213530/58956)):

```
interface Listener<T>{
    // ...
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final class SingletonListener {

    private SingletonListener() {
        assert false : "Uninstantiable";
    }

    public static <T> Listener<T> instance() {
        return SingletonListenerInstance.INSTANCE;
    }

    // Note - implements Listener without specifying type parameters!
    private enum SingletonListenerInstance implements Listener {
        INSTANCE;
        // Insert listener methods here
    }
}


// Usage:
Listener<Pony> ponyListener = SingletonListener.instance();
```

So what could this implementation do if it receives arguments of type `T`, or is expected to return values of (or relating to) type `T`? Well, not much, but more than nothing! Here's a more fleshed-out version with example implementations:

```
interface Listener<T> {
    void receive(T something);

    T process(T something);

    T produce();

    List<T> produceMany();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final class SingletonListener {

    private SingletonListener() {
        assert false : "Uninstantiable";
    }

    public static <T> Listener<T> instance() {
        return SingletonListenerInstance.INSTANCE;
    }

    // Note - implements Listener without specifying type parameters!
    private enum SingletonListenerInstance implements Listener {
        INSTANCE;
        // Insert listener methods here

        @Override
        public void receive(Object something) {
            // We can log what we receive because we know everything is an Object
            // and so has a toString method; we can also use other Object methods,
            // do reflection (or just ignore it and leave a no-op implementation)
            System.out.println("Received " + something);
        }

        @Override
        public Object process(Object something) {
            // We can return something we know to be of the right type, which in our
            // case typically is arguments we've received
            return something;
        }

        @Override
        public Object produce() {
            // Null is a valid value for all types
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List produceMany() {
            // Don't need any instances of the generic type to create an empty list
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `final class SingletonListener<T> {` ?

Comment: This code won't compile, and even if you modify it so that it does, it won't work with a Listener<T> that contains methods with generic arguments or return types. Thus it will only work with Listener, not Listener<T>.  It isn't a generic solution.

Comment: @user1677663 thanks for pointing out the non-compilability, fixed that. As for what the methods can do, turns out there are a few things you actually can do! Mostly useful for dummy/no-op implementations, of course, and you have to track of what's what or you'll end up with surprising `ClassCastException`s in the client code, but corner cases where this is useful can be conceived.

Comment: Thanks for fleshing it out enough that people can see what they are actually getting into with this approach!