# Is it possible to refactor these methods to avoid code duplication?

Tags: java, jpa, refactoring, code-duplication

I have a bunch of utility-like methods, which looks very similar, like:

```
public static void addLeadingAttorney(EventAttorneyModel newAttorney,
                                List<EventAttorneyModel> existingAttorneys) {
    for (EventAttorneyModel existingAttorney : existingAttorneys) {
        existingAttorney.setSequence(existingAttorney.getSequence() + 1);
    }
    newAttorney.setSequence(1L);
    existingAttorneys.add(0, newAttorney);
}


public static void addLeadingAttorney(CaseAttorneyModel newAttorney,
                                List<CaseAttorneyModel> existingAttorneys) {
    for (CaseAttorneyModel existingAttorney : existingAttorneys) {
        existingAttorney.setSequence(existingAttorney.getSequence() + 1);
    }
    newAttorney.setSequence(1L);
    existingAttorneys.add(0, newAttorney);
}
```

Classes `EventAttorneyModel` and `CaseAttorneyModel` are JPA entities and do not have common predecessors except for the `Object` class.

I wonder if there's a way I can get rid of duplicating the code, as there will be many such methods in future?

Comment: Is there a reason they do not have a common parent or interface?

Comment: If both classes implemented the same interface this would be very easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think best way would be to create an interface

```
interface AttorneyModel{

   public void setSequence(Long l);

}
```

and make 2 classes implement them, and have method signature like

```
public static <T extends AttorneyModel> void addLeadingAttorney(T newAttorney,
                                List<T> existingAttorneys) {
```

Comment: That's the way to go, imo. And repeat it for all other sets of classes.

Comment: No need for generics.  Just use AttorneyModel as the type.

Comment: I would go for it. The only my concern is how JPA will react if I add that interface?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can't pass `List<CaseAttorneyModel>` to `List<AttorneyModel>`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: In this case the constraint that leading attorney should have the same type would be lost.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis agreed that the code wont compile if we pass `List<CaseAttorneyModel>`, but we can pass `List<AttorneyModel>` and we can fill the list with `CaseAttorneyModel`, so both should work

Comment: @sanbhat If the parameter is `List<AttorneyModel>` and the list we want to pass as an argument is declared as `List<CaseAttorneyModel>`, the code won't compile.

Comment: I believe you were searching for this: `public static <T extends OrderedEntity> void addLeadingAttorney(T newAttorney, List<T> existingAttorneys)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could create a [generic class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) encapsulating both methods.

And you could make it a singleton class following the idea of the post below.-

[how to create a generic singleton class in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772362/how-to-create-a-generic-singleton-class-in-java)